# Joined reports with master-detail relationship

Tags: reporting, master-detail, custom-reports, joined-reports

I'm having problems trying to make a report of some custom objects, they're arranged like this:

A (detail) <-- B (master) --> C (detail of B)(master of D) --> D (detail)

Any ideas of how to get all of this in one report somehow because I am stumped!

Comment: Can you clarify the relationships on object C? It is the child of A and the parent of D, but what is its relationship to B?

Comment: I've mistyped, C is the child of B not A - hope that clarifies.

Comment: Do a joined report, first one would be `B with A`, second - `B with C` third `C with D` (to surface that last one you might have to create a `Custom Report Type`).